# Apache superset: how to export data as csv for all charts in a dashboard?

Tags: apache-superset

In apache superset, I see an 'Export CSV' option to export data as CSV for an individual chart. I have a dashboard which has many charts and I want to allow users to export data from all the charts in a single click. What would the easiest approach to achieve the same?

I see the `/superset/explore_json?csv=true` API can be invoked to export data for a chart. Can it be used for doing same for multiple charts in a single invocation? Or any other better approach?

Comment: Yes, Right now you can export slices individually from a Dashboard one by one, But not all the slices can be exported at once. This might need a PR.
You can create a ticket at issue tracker and maybe raise a SIP for this?

I am not sure, but the reason this does not exist right now is maybe due to the expensive nature of such operation.

Comment: Here is the associated Apache Superset [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/25370#discussion-5659811)